Corollary I.3.5.3 in Tamme's Introduction to Etale Cohomology
Corollary 3.5.3, page 62 in Tamme's Introduction to Etale Cohomology, says that an abelian sheaf $F$, on a topology $(\mathcal C, \tau)$, is flabby iff ($*$) $H^q(U,F)=0$ for all objects $U$ in $\mathcal C$ and $q\gt 0$.
In particular I'm interested in the proof of the "if" direction: in the textbook is invoked another result, Corollary 3.4.6, but it seems to me that it can be done without it. The assumption ($*$) is equivalent to $R^q\iota(F)=0$ for $q\gt 0$, where $\iota$ is the inclusion functor of the abelian sheaves into the abelian presheaves. So the spectral sequence with terms $H^p(\{U_i\to U\}_i,R^q\iota(F))$ collapses on the row $q=0$, so $H^p(\{U_i\to U\}_i,\iota(F))$ is isomorphic to $H^p(U,F)$, so $H^p(\{U_i\to U\}_i,\iota(F))=0$ for $p\gt 0$.
The good thing about this proof (if it is correct) is that we don't have to make assumption about the existence of fibered products. So I have two questions:

Is my idea for the proof ok?
Why doesn't Tamme require the existence of any fibered product in 3.5.3 and 3.4.6? I get that in 3.4.6 the existence of the fibered products $U_{i_0}\times_U\dots\times_UU_{i_n}$ for any covering $\{U_i\to U\}_i$ could be implicit in the assumption that $H^q(U_{i_0}\times_U\dots\times_UU_{i_n} ,F)=0$ for $q\gt 0$, but in 3.5.3 it should be necessary in order to use 3.4.6 or am I wrong?

